# How to use Jquery blur function properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if this is a proper usage of the `.blur` function, since I have a larger code with many validations and a `.blur` for each one and does not work, maybe I'm doing it wrong. I will comment how I understand it.

```
$(document).ready(myFunction); //.ready function runs myFunction

//"userinfo" is a text field that when loses focus it runs validateuser function

function myFunction(){
$("userinfo").blur(validateuser);
}

function validateuser(){
var user = $("#userinfo").val(); //variable stores data input from the user

 //validates that the user contains text only, showing messages accordingly

 if(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(user)){ 
   $("#msg").html("The information is correct.");
    }else{
   $("#msg").html("The information is not correct");
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `$("#userinfo").blur(validateuser);`?

Comment: can you aslso share the html code & userInfo is it an id or class?

Comment: @PeterKA Gosh, people in this page are going to exile me one of these days. I forgot the #.

Comment: @SgtAJ No need for parenthesis, the issue was the missing #. I ran it and now it works. I appreciate all your answers and my apologies for being such a noob.

Comment: Glad that was helpful. If you have so many elements to use similar code, I hope you not given each element the same ID. If so, please change `id="userinfo"` to `class="userinfo"` or add the class ` userinfo` if the elements already have a class attribute. Then in your code change `#userinfo` to `.userinfo`.

Comment: @PeterKA Yes, the ID's are all different. Thank you!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript :

```
function validateuser(){
   var user = $("#userinfo").val();
   if(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(user)){ 
      $("#msg").html("The information is correct.");
   }else{
      $("#msg").html("The information is not correct");
   }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#userinfo").blur(function(){
      validateuser();
   });
});
```

Use this code.You can create function within $.ready() or outside.It doesn't matter.Call that validateuser() function when $("#userinfo").blur() event.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the #. check below for correction

```
function myFunction(){
$("#userinfo").blur(validateuser);
}
```